# Representing a limited-range integer with an enum in Rust?

Tags: rust, enums, transmute

I need an integral type that as a predefined limited range that includes 0, and want to implement like this:

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum X { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H }

impl From<u8> for X {
    fn from(x: u8) -> X {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(x & 0b111) }
    }
}
```

When I need the integer value, I would cast with `as u8`. Arithmetic ops would be implemented by casting to `u8` then converting back into the enum using `from`. And because I limit the range with the bitand when converting from u8 to the enum, I'm always in range of the enum.

Some benefits I can see are that the range is known to the compiler so it can skip bounds checking, and enum optimizations such as representing `Option<X>` as 1 byte.

A drawback I can see via assembly is that I incur `and al, 7` every time I convert to enum, but I can live with that.

Is this a sound transmutation of `u8` into the enum? What are other drawbacks of representing a limited range integer this way, if any?

Comment: This is sound, but if the type is meant to be numeric, a newtype around the underlying numeric type is probably better. And you should probably implement `TryFrom` instead of `From` so you can signal errors on out of range values. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ecf014fb5978b64cf146b4dbf6aa322f)

Comment: @cdhowie thanks. I'm considering this for the benefits of informing the compiler about the range limit, which the newtype won't do, unfortunately. If I could do that directly to an integer type, that'd be better, but I can't.

Comment: The newtype approach indeed can't handle the `Option` optimization, though it can handle bounds checking at compile time given an appropriate `const` constructor function that panics on out-of-range values.

Comment: It is worth noting that this `transmute` compiles ([I checked](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ba59d464ecd467ce5e46967e269b648)) to exactly the same assembly as  explicitly doing a match on each possibility:  `match x & 0b111 { ... , _ => unreachable!() }`. So you really don't need to use `unsafe` here.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes, almost :) Unfortunately, I ran into this problem, which turned me to the unsafe transmute: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/106658. The other problem with a match statement is that in my real use cases I've got 64 or 128 options, and so the match is large. The compiler then does not automatically inline, requiring me to inline directly, and in my tests this cause more and more downstream problems. So in the end, transmute seems easier at the cost of one unsafe.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything *wrong* with this transmutation, in that it is likely sound. However, I believe it is unnecessary.

If performance is critical for your application, you should test on your target arch, but I used the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7a5d95201cb1c442160a4bd26d308ef) to show the generated ASM (for whatever arch the playground runs on):

Your version:

```
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum X { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H }

impl From<u8> for X {
    fn from(x: u8) -> X {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(x & 0b111) }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
fn do_it_x(a: u8) -> X {
    a.into()
}
```

Explicit match:

```
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Y { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H }

impl From<u8> for Y {
    fn from(y: u8) -> Y {
        match y & 0b111 {
            0 => Y::A,
            1 => Y::B,
            2 => Y::C,
            3 => Y::D,
            4 => Y::E,
            5 => Y::F,
            6 => Y::G,
            7 => Y::H,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
fn do_it_y(a: u8) -> Y {
    a.into()
}
```

The resulting assembly (from the playground at least) is:

```
do_it_x:
    pushq   %rax
    movb    %dil, %al
    movb    %al, 7(%rsp)
    movzbl  %al, %edi
    callq   <T as core::convert::Into<U>>::into
    movb    %al, 6(%rsp)
    movb    6(%rsp), %al
    popq    %rcx
    retq

do_it_y:
    pushq   %rax
    movb    %dil, %al
    movb    %al, 7(%rsp)
    movzbl  %al, %edi
    callq   <T as core::convert::Into<U>>::into
    movb    %al, 6(%rsp)
    movb    6(%rsp), %al
    popq    %rcx
    retq
```

Comment: Looking at the ASM in your playground, the interesting functions are `<playground::X as core::convert::From<u8>>::from:` and `<playground::Y as core::convert::From<u8>>::from:`. The second one is a switch-case implementation and a lot longer than the first one. If performance and code size is important (should always be IMO), I would use the `transmute` solution.